# Can Will Paginate be used normally with Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I know normally you can use pagination like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 5)
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end
```

But what about something more complex like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      #This line will be for me to have an association because Products has_many Prices
      @prices = Price.joins(:product).where(:product_id => [1,2,3]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end
```

I haven't found documentation on Sunspot's pagination or any in depth tutorials. Is it possible to use will_paginate normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will paginate works on any array object.

The search returns and array right?  so you can do something like:

```
search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end

@search = search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:rows])
```

Comment: that raises undefined method `paginate' for #<Sunspot::Search::StandardSearch:0x10e134728>

Comment: So for you the search returns a Sunspot Search object?  It should return and array

Comment: yeah, i can't make any sense of it. I moved code around and tried different combinations until i was seeing stars. It took 2 days, but some how it works now.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Knowing me i had some simple synytax problem.

Comment: @EmSta You are going to  need to give more details about your issue.

Comment: @drhenner change it to `search.results.paginate(parameters)`