# Sunspot solr, fetch only a limited number of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

How does one fetch only a limited number of records for sunspot solr? Since I have 2000 fake profiles It tries to load them every time the page refresh. I want to paginate and fetch only a limited number of records instead.

using will paginate and sunspot solr to list the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick ( with will paginate)

```
      paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 50)
```

Answer (score 3):

The sunspot wiki talks about [pagination](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Ordering-and-pagination).

Here are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626780/rails-sunspot-and-will-paginate-issue) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116755/can-will-paginate-be-used-normally-with-sunspot) [examples](http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=235).